# Cumulative list by dates

Tags: sql

I have a list of products by date -

```
2020-01-01   A
2020-01-02   B
2020-01-02   C
2020-01-02   D
2020-01-03   B
2020-01-03   C
2020-01-03   E
```

I want the results to look like -

```
2020-01-01   A

2020-01-02   A
2020-01-02   B
2020-01-02   C
2020-01-02   D

2020-01-03   A
2020-01-03   B
2020-01-03   C
2020-01-03   D
2020-01-03   E
```

cumulative list of all products by date.
What would be the most efficient way to solve this

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
select d.date, p.product
from (select t.product, min(date) as min_date
      from t
      group by t.product
     ) p
     (select distinct date from t) d
     on p.min_date <= d.date
order by d.date, p.product;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `cross join` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.date, tt.product
FROM table t CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT product FROM table t) tt INNER JOIN
     table t1
     ON t1.date = t.date AND t1.product >= tt.product;
```

However, simple inner join would also work no need to use sub-query :

```
select distinct t.date, tt.product
from table t inner join
     table tt
     on tt.date <= t.date;
```